# How to change timezone in heroku nodejs dashboard?

Tags: node.js, heroku, timezone, heroku-toolbelt

I was wondering if any of you had experience in changing the timezone in the heroku dashboard.
I have heard there are 2 methods.
Setting one of the config vars(in settings) to TZ like:

Key:

```
TZ
```

Argument:

```
"America/Los_Angeles"
```

or putting this in a nodejs script:

```
proccess.env.tz = "America/Los_Angeles"
```

Is there anything I should be doing different to change the app's time in heroku and/or nodeJS?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two alternatives you said are basically the same, they are just setting  it on a different place (heroku config vars on first case, and your code on the second), but as the question is about how to change on heroku dashboard, I'd go with the first answer.

The only thing should be different, is the argument to Heroku config vars, that should be without quotes